# Does Google Play ask to accept custom permission as like in built permissions in case of auto update

Tags: android, permissions

I am working on an app where I am using a custom `permission` as defined by another developer in their SDK.

According to Google, if we add a pre-defined `permission`, such as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, then, when a user updates the app, they will be prompted to approve this new permission. This happens before the app is updated; if the user does not accept, the app is not updated.

Now, we want to add in this custom `permission`. Will the Play Store still ask users to accept this new permission prior to updating the app when we release the new version on the Play store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes all permissions are required to be approved by the user. If the updated version has new permissions : grouped or others, they need to be approved by user.

From Google's policies:

> Users who wish to have full control over new individual permissions being added to an app can review individual permissions for an app at any time, or may consider turning off auto-updates for one or more apps. Any permissions that are not part of a permissions group, including those that are not shown in the main permissions screen, will be shown in the "Other" group.

**Update**

From M the permission model will change. Users will control the permissions at runtime. Good for users but more work for developers, as now we have to handle the permission denial. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html).

Comment: what If I set android:protectionLevel to  "signature" ?

Answer (score 4):

When people download your app they have to accept the permissions that you set in your manifest.

If you set a new permission in the android manifest of your app, then people who have downloaded your app will need to accept the new permission first. So if you update your app and you have new permission it won't auto update and people need to first accept it in the google play store.

From Google's support page:

> When an app updates, it may need to use additional
>   capabilities or information controlled by permissions.
>
> If you have automatic updates enabled, you won't need to review or
>   accept these permissions as long as they are included in a permissions
>   group you already accepted for that app.
>
> If the app needs access to an additional permissions group, you'll be
>   asked to accept the update, even if you've set an app to update
>   automatically.
>
> If you prefer to review each update manually, you can change your
>   update settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Google play will ask users to approve custom permissions.**

Google clearly mentions that

"If the app needs access to an additional permissions group, you'll be asked to accept the update, even if you've set an app to update automatically."

and

"Developers may automatically add additional permissions within each group"

Since custom permissions do not belong do any permission group, they are shown in other permissions and when updating an app if new permissions are added to others group, play store will ask users to approve those permissions.

Official Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972 (open link and click on other)
This page says **"Note: If an app adds a permission that is in the "Other" group, you'll always be asked to review the change before downloading an update."**